# Scanner adding blank lines with scanning in from a file

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read in from a file using a Scanner then append these to an Array. However when I do so the Scanner seems to be picking up blank lines and assigning these blanks lines to indexes in the array.

I've tried a fair few different ways of working to no avail and was just wondering if any came along the same problem and new why it would be doing this?

The format of the file is as follows:

F:\Data\SFW3\FOLDER

F:\Data\SFW3\FOLDER

F:\Data\SFW3\FOLDER

F:\Data\SFW3\FOLDER

Any ideas would be greatly welcomed.

```
public void scanFiles() throws NoSuchElementException {
    Scanner sc = null;
    System.out.println("Sage 2015 is Installed on this machine");
    int i = 0;

    try {
        String line;
        File companyFile = new File(sageFolders[8] + "\\COMPANY"); 
        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(companyFile)));

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(i);
            currentFolders.add(i,line);
            System.out.println("At Index" + i + ": " + currentFolders.get(i));
            i++; 
        }

        sc.close();    
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found: Moving onto next Version"); 
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only explanation I can see for why you have blank lines in the output is that there are blank lines in the input.  Is this the case?

Comment: Scanner::nextLine() documentation says that "Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator" it seems you have blank lines in you input as @TimBiegeleisen has mentioned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `String.trim().length()` to find out if it is a blank line and if not do not add it

```
System.out.println(i);

if (String.trim().length() > 0) {
    currentFolders.add(i,line);
    System.out.println("At Index" + i + ": " + currentFolders.get(i));
}

i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To achieve your task, try below code:

 while(sc.hasNextLine())
      {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        if(null != line && line.trim().length() > 0){
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println(i);
        currentFolders.add(i,line);
        System.out.println("At Index" + i + ": " + currentFolders.get(i));
        i++; 
      }
      }
```